# How do you express that a set has more elements than another

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I wanted to know if you can express that a set has more elements than another set, because I don't know if A > B would be correct

Also, is this a correct way to express myself mathematically?

R ∈ [0,1] > N ∈ [0,∞]

I am really bad with math notations since I mostly just like to understand the concepts, but expressing ideas with symbols seems more efficient, so if anyone would care to help that would be appreciated!

Comment: Yes, your conjecture is true, provided you are referring to $|[0,1]\subset\mathbb R|$ and $|\mathbb N|$; on the left, we have an uncountable infinity, and on the right, a countable infinity.  This is where we need to compare them via Cardinality, which is not well represented by "how many elements", because both have an infinite number of elements.

Comment: The use of notation is wrong, but it is too confusing to tell what you want it to mean, so it is not possible to correct it.

Comment: I think in your last question, you simply mean $\ \vert\ [0,1]\ \vert\ > \vert \mathbb{N} \vert\ $, since $\ [0,1]\ $ by definition is all the real numbers between $0$ and $1$ inclusive, and $\ \mathbb{N}\ $ means all the positive integers. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 4):

The notation that is used is $|A| > |B|$ to mean that $A$ has a larger size than $B$. In the case of finite sets, this overlaps with our intuitive notion of $A$ having more elements that $B$. For infinite sets, it means roughly the same thing except it would formally be defined as "there exists an injection from $B$ into $A$ and no injection from $A$ into $B$."

Answer (score 3):

We usually write $|A|>|B|,$ where $|A|$ means the “cardinality of $A.$” When $A$ is finite, the cardinality is essentially the number of elements.

We write $B\subseteq A$ (or sometimes $B\subset A$) if every element of $B$ is in $A.$

We write $B\subsetneq A$ if $B\subseteq A$ but but not all elements of $A$ are in $B$ - that is, if $A\neq B.$

When $A$ is finite, and $B\subsetneq A,$ then $|B|<|A|.$ But that is not true for infinite $A.$ For infinite $A,$ if $B\subsetneq A$ Then all we can say is $|B|\leq |A|.$

Comment: But isn't the number of real values between 0 and 1 greater than the number of positive natural values? If so couldn't we say that |A| > |B| even if they are infinite, or do we have to use ≥ in the case of infinite sets?

Comment: You can say $|A|>|B|$ for infinite sets, you just can’t conclude it just from knowing that  $B\subsetneq A.$ You can from finite sets, and many beginners intuit that infinite cardinalities should also have this property. @4ntoine12

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can express this with a brief notation. Most will accept and understand: $$| \{t\,\in\,\mathbb{R}:0\leq t\leq1\}| \,>\, |\{1,2,3,\dots\} |$$

Comment: I know that | while defining a set means "such that", but what does the : stand for? Does it mean the same thing but is simply a different way of writing it? Also thanks for this answer it helped me understand notations!

Comment: Yes, exactly. The colon means the same as a vertical line in set notation, and means "such that", or "with the condition that".

Comment: I have come to favor the colon over the vertical pipe, maybe because of this type of situation. I don't like $| \{t\,\in\,\mathbb{R}|0\leq t\leq1\}|$ too much.

Comment: @311411. The vertical pipe has many other uses, so I prefer the colon too. E.g. $\{|x|: |x^2+x|<1\}$ versus $\{|x|\,|\,|x^2+x|<1\}.$ Or without extra spaces $\{|x|||x^2+x|<1\}.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Unfortunately, the colon also has other uses. E.g $\{ f : V \to V : \text{$f$ is linear}\}$ vs. $\{ f : V \to V~|~\text{$f$ is linear} \}$.

Comment: Great point, I will remember that example. Welcome back to my life, vertical pipe! $\{f:S\to T\,|\,f\,\text{has a certain property}\}$@EikeSchulte

Comment: @EikeSchulte . In some very old geometry texts you may see AB:CD::EF:GH where AB,CD,EF,GH are line-segments. It means AB/CD=EF/GH.